# Django 2 displaying posts by category

Tags: django

In my Django 2.1 app I have the following views:

```
def single(request, post_slug):
    post = get_object_or_404(Post, slug=post_slug)
    suggested = Post.objects.all()[:2]
    context = {'post': post, 'suggested': suggested}
    return render(request, 'single.html', context)

def course(request,post_tags):
    posts = get_object_or_404(Post, tags=post_tags)
    posts = Post.objects.filter(is_course=True).filter(tags__contains=post_tags).order_by('lesson_order')
    return render(request, 'learn.html', {'posts': posts})
```

and urls.py

```
    path('courses/<tag:post_tags/', app.views.course, name='learn'),
    path( '<slug:post_slug>/', app.views.single, name='single')
```

the single post works fine but courses/tagname doesn't it returns a 404 although I am sure that the tags I am trying to load exist.

I think I am making a trivial mistake somewhere! thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: You forgot to close the bracket `>` (in your first `path`).

Comment: Furthermore `tag` is *not* a path converter (unless you defined it somewhere), so you probably should use `str:` (or `path:`).

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem thank you! you were right about the braket (sorry for being so blind!) and I now got the invalid converter error. if. I change my path to path: I get        ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax :(

Comment: so you wrote `'courses/<path:post_tags>/`?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem thanks this worked but a new problem: MultipleObjectsReturned at /courses/html/
get() returned more than one Post -- it returned 13!   my idea was to get all the posts by category in the tag..big logic mistake? :)

Comment: you should remove the `posts = get_object_or_404(Post, tags=post_tags)`, this will indeed error if there are *multiple* results, the second line is (as far as I can see) fine.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem bingo!! thanks a lot - feel free to post a reply. It is trivial but some beginners might not know it. Also for my information and not to stay totally stupid on this why the second path with single worked and tag was not a path converter ? are path and slug Django keywords ?

Comment: no, these are path converters https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/http/urls/#path-converters , you can define your own (and register these), these are just "builtin" ones, to ease defining paths of course, since otherwise it would only result in more work.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem all clear thanks again also for the link to the docs.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem I am wondering..how would be an elegant way to return 404 if a tag/category  does not exist?

Comment: you can use `get_list_or_404`: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/http/shortcuts/#get-list-or-404

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem thanks again if you want to submit an answer I will certainly select it !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two errors with your `path(..)` specifications:

1. you forgot to close the angle bracket (`>`); and
2. `tag` is not a valid [*path converter* [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/http/urls/#path-converters), we can use another one like `str` or `path`.

So we can fix the two errors and obtain the following `path(..)`:

```
path('courses/<path:post_tags>/', app.views.course, name='learn'),
```

In the view itself, you probably do *not* want to use [**`get_object_or_404`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/shortcuts/#get-object-or-404), since if there are multiple `Post`s that have the given tags, then it will raise an error. You probably want to use [**`get_list_or_404`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/shortcuts/#get-list-or-404):

```
from django.shortcuts import get_list_or_404

def course(request,post_tags):
    posts = get_list_or_404(Post.objects.order_by('lesson_order'), is_course=True, tags__contains=post_tags)
    return render(request, 'learn.html', {'posts': posts})
```